# Azure SQL Database trigger to insert audit info into Azure Table

Tags: sql-server, azure, triggers, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

I am working on a database auditing solution and was thinking of having SQL Server triggers take care of changes and inserting them into an auditing table. Since this is a SQL Azure Database and will be fairly large I am concerned about the cost of a growing database due to auditing.

In order to cut down on the costs needed for auditing purposes, I am considering storing the audit table (or tables) in Azure Tables instead of Azure SQL databases. So the question becomes, how to get the SQL Server trigger to get the changed data into Azure Tables?

The only thing I can come up with is to have an audit table (or tables) in SQL Databases so the trigger can insert the rows locally, and then have a Worker Role every X seconds pull any rows from that and move them to Azure Tables and delete from the SQL Database table so it doesn't grow large.

Is there a better way to do this integration?  Can I somehow put a message in a queue from a trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure SQL Database (formerly SQL Azure) doesn't support CLR (hence no `EXTERNAL NAME` trigger parameter) so there's no way for your triggers to do anything outside of T-SQL. If you want audit content to go to a table, you could take the approach you came up with (temporarily write to SQL table, then move content periodically to Table). There are other approaches you could take (and this would be opinion/subjective, frowned upon here), but going with the queue concept for a minute, since you asked about queues, and illustrating what you could do with Azure Queues:

You could use an Azure queue to specify an item to insert/update in your SQL database. The queue processing code could then be responsible for performing the update and writing to the Azure table. Since the queue messages must be explicitly deleted after processing, you could simply repeat the queue message processing if something failed during execution (e.g. you write to SQL but fail before writing to table storage). The message eventually becomes visible for reading again, if you don't delete it before its timeout value. As long as your operations are idempotent, you'd be ok with this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

A cheaper solution than using worker roles would be to use a combination of Azure Scheduled Tasks (you can enable them for free to run every 15 min within [Mobile Apps](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/solutions/mobile/)) and [Azure Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/solutions/web/).  Basically the way it would work is to run this scheduled job every 15 min which would make an HTTP call to some code you have running within your Azure Web Site.  This code would do the same work you had outlined for your worker role.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use SQL Server System-Versioned temporal tables to automatically handle the writing of audited record (i.e., changes) to corresponding history tables.