# AzureSQLDB- Sending table update to invoke a function

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-queues

I am working on Azure SQLDB- and idea is to send a messages to signalR hub  which will connect with the clients. The volume of traffic will be low (around 1000-2000 messages per day at maximum, and 1-2s latency is fine)

Rather than poll at periodic intervals, we want to use Azure functions to make the data pull, only when there is an update. I understand AzureDB has functional limitations and triggers cannot invoke the Azure function directly due to lack of CLR support

[Azure SQL Database trigger to insert audit info into Azure Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893845/azure-sql-database-trigger-to-insert-audit-info-into-azure-table)

What are the best options

- Should I populate a queue - which acts as a trigger for function? Again,how do I populate this queue?
- I can use Service Bus - but would prefer to keep it simple

Appreciate any pointers and guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I guess you have something, let's call it `Client`, which update data in SQL Database:

`Client` `->` `Database`

So, you have roughly two options:

1. Change the `Client` to also insert a queue item every time it updates the database. Then your function will be triggered by queue items, and will send the notifications.

   ```
   Client -> Database
          -> Queue -> Function -> SignalR
   ```
2. Make your function periodically poll the database and detect updates itself (timer trigger).

   ```
   Client -> Database <- (pulls) Function -> SignalR
   ```

   It sound like you already poll from the clients at the moment, so it probably won't get worse. But 1-2s target latency will mean polling every second, which might be expensive depending on the query.