# Event alerts in Azure SQL using auditing

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-sql-database

We are looking to get alerts on **specific tables** in a Azure DB to initiate actions.These could be 
a) calling a Azure Search indexer API so that changes get indexed in near-real time every time the datasource changes
b) push updates to users via SignalR when there is an update

I understand AzureDB has functional limitations and triggers cannot invoke the Azure function directly due to lack of CLR support. 
[Azure SQL Database trigger to insert audit info into Azure Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893845/azure-sql-database-trigger-to-insert-audit-info-into-azure-table)

Given the triggers in Azure cannot invoke APIs, I was told that we could get information on database updates via the auditing. However, the auditing seems to be at the blob level- not at a table level

Given the multiple changes underway, it would be quite a task and time-delay to check out for the event of interest from the blob.

While there is a line around the blob auditing being configurable(supports **higher granularity object-level auditing**), I couldn't find an approach to limit blob updates to certain table alone. Any pointers would be appreciated

Also, given blob auditing seems to be built for threat detection/ regulatory purposes,any issues using this for event alerts?

Answer (score 3):

Additional info on granular Blob Auditing in Azure SQL DB (including limiting the audit policy to specific tables/views) can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt695939.aspx

Please note that we have also created the following OMS integration app for advanced analysis of Audit logs - you can use it to push the Blob audit logs into OMS, and then create customized alerts in OMS on top of the audit logs (this is a temporary solution, until our fully integrated OMS/Log Analytics solution is available):
https://github.com/Microsoft/Azure-SQL-DB-auditing-OMS-integration

Best Regards,
Gilad Mittelman

SQL Security, Microsoft

Comment: could you pls recheck the link: I get 'The page you requested could not be found'